# How does $doCheck not have any impact if $doChanges is also called?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-controller

[AngularJS official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks) provided the following information in this regard.

> `$doCheck()` - Called on each turn of the digest cycle. Provides an opportunity to detect and act on changes. Any actions that you wish to take in response to the changes that you detect must be invoked from this hook; implementing this has no effect on when `$onChanges` is called. For example, this hook could be useful if you wish to perform a deep equality check, or to check a Date object, changes to which would not be detected by Angular's change detector and thus not trigger $onChanges. This hook is invoked with no arguments; if detecting changes, you must store the previous value(s) for comparison to the current values.

I've explored on the web but could not find any information related to how calling `$onChanges` will makes the calls to `$doCheck` void. Someone please provide more information.

Comment: How are you inferring that calling $onChanges will invalidate $doCheck from this documentation. They seem to be two separate hooks.

Answer (score 1):

The `$onChanges` and `$doCheck` hook can easily live side-by-side. The `$doCheck` hook doesn't effect the `$onChanges` hook at all. Of course fields checked in the `$doCheck` hook no longer need to be handled in the `$onChanges` hook. In Angular 2 it’s even recommended to not use these 2 hooks together.